# What did the equitable of the citizens exactly dislike about Ananus, in Josephus' reference to James?

Tags: christianity, 1st-century

Josephus' reference to James the brother of Jesus

> And now Caesar, upon hearing the death of Festus, sent Albinus into
> Judea, as procurator. But the king deprived Joseph of the high
> priesthood, and bestowed the succession to that dignity on the son of
> Ananus, who was also himself called Ananus. Now the report goes that
> this eldest Ananus proved a most fortunate man; for he had five sons
> who had all performed the office of a high priest to God, and who had
> himself enjoyed that dignity a long time formerly, which had never
> happened to any other of our high priests. But this younger Ananus,
> who, as we have told you already, took the high priesthood, was a bold
> man in his temper, and very insolent; he was also of the sect of the
> Sadducees, who are very rigid in judging offenders, above all the rest
> of the Jews, as we have already observed; when, therefore, Ananus was
> of this disposition, he thought he had now a proper opportunity.
> Festus was now dead, and Albinus was but upon the road; so he
> assembled the sanhedrin of judges, and brought before them the brother
> of Jesus, who was called Christ, whose name was James, and some
> others; and when he had formed an accusation against them as breakers
> of the law, he delivered them to be stoned: but as for those who
> seemed the most equitable of the citizens, and such as were the most
> uneasy at the breach of the laws, they disliked what was done; they
> also sent to the king, desiring him to send to Ananus that he should
> act so no more, for that what he had already done was not to be
> justified; nay, some of them went also to meet Albinus, as he was upon
> his journey from Alexandria, and informed him that it was not lawful
> for Ananus to assemble a sanhedrin without his consent. Whereupon
> Albinus complied with what they said, and wrote in anger to Ananus,
> and threatened that he would bring him to punishment for what he had
> done; on which king Agrippa took the high priesthood from him, when he
> had ruled but three months, and made Jesus, the son of Damneus, high
> priest.

[Flavius Josephus: Antiquities of the Jews Book 20, Chapter 9, 1](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0146%3Abook%3D20%3Awhiston%20chapter%3D9%3Awhiston%20section%3D1),

Did they dislike, that he delivered them to be stoned, because they knew that they did nothing to justify their execution?
or their objection was merely because it was not lawful for Ananus to assemble a sanhedrin without Albinus'consent?

Comment: This seems more relevant to the [Biblical Hermenutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/) stack.

Comment: Except its not from the bible...